# Layout that breaks views to second line line, if not enough space is available

Tags: android, layout

I have two switches next to each other in a LinearLayout.

The problem is that with API level 20 the switches take a lot of space:

[image]

With API level 23 (I don't know at which API level it changed and it doesn't matter here) the switches became more minimalistic:

[image]

With which layout (and how) can I achieve that in the first picture the second switch goes below the first one (so to speak in the second line), but only if there is not enough space to display the label properly?

I don't want to use third party libraries if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't achieve this with standard layouts. But you can use [FlexboxLayout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout).

I also advise you to use `android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat` instead of `android.widget.Switch`, so switch will look like the same (material style) on different versions of android.